# checking whole boolean of NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsmutablearray

I have an array that I am filling with boolean values in the following code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
  int checkVal = [(NSNumber *)[__diceValue objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    if(checkVal == matchVal){
        [_diceMatch replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:y]];
    }
}
```

Whats the shortest way to write a conditional to check the array "_diceMatch" for all true values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array can only contain the values "true" (`@YES`) or "false" (`@NO`)
then you can simply check for the absence of `@NO`:

```
if (![_diceMatch containsObject:@NO]) {
   // all elements are "true"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUInteger numberOfTrueValues = 0;

for (NSNumber *value in _diceMatch) {
   if ([value boolValue]) {
      numberOfTrueValues++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Shortest way? maybe not. Easiest way? Yes

```
- (BOOL)isDictMatchAllTrue {
    for (NSNumber *n in _dictMatch) {
        if (![n boolValue]) return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

or you don't like writing loop

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:_diceMatch];
return set.count == 1 && [[set anyObject] boolValue];
```

Note: first version return `YES` when array is empty but second version return `NO`.

You can add

```
if (_dictMatch.count == 0) return YES; //or NO
```

to fix it.